# Small files allocateing huge amout of disk space

Tags: files, filesystems, encryption, veracrypt

I have a 20GB encrypted (VeraCrypt) container. On that container I'm storing small files. 200.000 files and the same amount of folders with an averrage filesize of maybe 10KB. Because the container reached it's limit, I created a new one (60 GB).

But after I copied the data to the new Container 55GB if the diskspace was used. The filesystem is exfat and I tried every cluster size from 4 to 128kb but there is no change. At least with a small cluster size I expected a better disk usage - but no change.

Do you have any ideas what else can I do or what I'm doing wrong? Maybe exfat is the wrong filesystem for that kind of data? My only limitations is, that the container should be readable with Linux and Windows.

Comment: Are you running of of space or out of inodes? `df` should tell.

Comment: df -h shows /dev/mapper/veracrypt1           70G   61G   10G  86% /mnt/crypt and df -i shows /dev/mapper/veracrypt1          573406 491952   81454   86% /mnt/crypt